# Update view from controller loop - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

In one of my controllers, I have a DO WHILE loop which is reading in and manipulating data from Twitter API before returning Json data to be used by chartjs in view.

The problem is that each loop can take around 1 second due to how the API works and sometimes I have to wait quite a while for the whole process to be finalized and view updated.

The ideal solution I can imagine would be if somehow the chart in the view were passed data from **each** DO WHILE loop until the whole process was over. The chart would change according to the new data received, without refreshing the whole page. Is this possible? I am quite new to ASP.NET so I'm unsure about the tools at my disposal.

I tried ajax but it's my understanding that ajax makes a call to the controller to get data, not the other way around (and I actually want the data to be passed to the chart every time a single loop's calculation is done).

Comment: depends, if you can call the twitter API directly from ajax you could do it like that

Comment: Yes, there are a few options: 1) create an api endpoint which fetches only one record, with an offset. 2) use a push-like endpoint, for example with SignalR.

Comment: Async controllers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to look into something like SignalR to push data to the client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: Ajax is a good choice. The request to the controller would only initialize the page with an empty graph. Your JS code can then issue calls directly to the twitter Api to load the data or you can call a controller method if you prefer to do it server side.